# how to make a list in a Class and get acces to it in the main program

Tags: c#, class, windows-forms-designer

I have 10 doctors (laeger) which each have different information like adress,email, zip code and so on.
Here is a partial of my class code:

> public class laegeinfo
>
> public int yderNr { get; set; }
>
> public string solo { get; set; }
>
> public int flermands { get; set; }
>
> public string sidsteBesoeg { get; set; }

how can I make a class, and then acces these members from within my main program ?
i have tried for several days, and I keep getting errors like " infinite loop or recursion" 
so far i have written each member in each button handler for my application, but I know there has to be a better solution.
this is my code from the main program (partial) so far:

```
laegeInfo laege9 = new laegeInfo()
        {
            yderNr = 09123,
            solo = "Nej",
            flermands = "Ja",
            besoeg = 5,
            FMKBesoeg = "Ja",
            sidsteBesoeg = new DateTime(2015,7, 6)

        };
        laegeInfo laege10 = new laegeInfo()
        {
            yderNr = 10102,
            solo = "Nej",
            flermands = "Ja",
            besoeg = 5,
            FMKBesoeg = "Ja",
            sidsteBesoeg = new DateTime (2016,6, 9) 
        };
        List<laegeInfo> laegers = new List<laegeInfo>(10);
        laegers.Add(laege1);
        laegers.Add(laege2);
        laegers.Add(laege3);
        laegers.Add(laege4);
        laegers.Add(laege5);
        laegers.Add(laege6);
        laegers.Add(laege7);
        laegers.Add(laege8);
        laegers.Add(laege9);
        laegers.Add(laege10);


        var UserInput = int.Parse(txtBesogYderNr.Text);
        var laege = laegers.SingleOrDefault(L => L.yderNr == UserInput);
        if (laege != null)


            foreach (laegeInfo L in laegers)
            {
                txtFlermands.Text = L.flermands.ToString();
                txtSolo.Text = L.solo.ToString();
                txtAntalBesog.Text = L.besoeg.ToString();
                txtSidsteBesog.Text = L.sidsteBesoeg.ToShortTimeString();
                txtFMKBesog.Text = L.FMKBesoeg.ToString();
```

Comment: your code is incomplete, and post only the necessary code

Comment: my application is working when I have the  doctors written in the main program.